# Triggering spark job from REST executes the job endlessly

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to trigger spark job with hidden REST Api in a cluster. I am able to trigger spark job but It keeps on executing again and again unless I explicitly kill it.

My request looks like the following

```
curl -X POST http://sparkmaster:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
    "action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
    "appArgs" : ["10"],
    "appResource" : "file:/path/to/myapp.jar",
    "clientSparkVersion" : "1.6.1",
    "environmentVariables" : {
        "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
    },
    "mainClass" : "com.brevitaz.app.Main",
    "sparkProperties" : {
        "spark.jars" : "file:/path/to/myapp.jar",
        "spark.driver.supervise" : "true",
        "spark.app.name" : "MySparkJob",
        "spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
        "spark.submit.deployMode" : "client",
        "spark.master" : "spark://sparkmaster:6066"
    }
}'
```

Response

```
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20170524105859-0022",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "1.6.1",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20170524105859-0022",
  "success" : true
}
```

I am expecting to submit the job and just execute it once. Is there any way to achieve the same in spark?

I am open for other ways to trigger the spark job as well. All I need is to trigger execution of spark job once from my scala based web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified "spark.driver.supervise" : "true" in your API call which seems to be causing application to launch again every time it exits with non-zero return code.

Refer below from official spark's official documentation.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

> Additionally, standalone cluster mode supports restarting your
>   application automatically if it exited with non-zero exit code. To use
>   this feature, you may pass in the --supervise flag to spark-submit
>   when launching your application.

Please try with setting the supervise flag as false. Hope this helps.